# C# Indexoutofrange Arrays school project error

Tags: c#, arrays

I have some C# code below. The problem is when I try to remove from the listed box it throws an error. I know this isn't the best way to do this. This is for school and I am only allowed to use arrays. Just looking for some input. Error is indexoutofrange. Problem occurs when trying to delete a name.

```
private void deletebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    addressbook[lstContacts.SelectedIndex].firstnamestring = "";
    addressbook[lstContacts.SelectedIndex].lastnamestring = "";
    addressbook[lstContacts.SelectedIndex].addressstring = "";
    addressbook[lstContacts.SelectedIndex].citystring = "";
    addressbook[lstContacts.SelectedIndex].statestring= "";
    addressbook[lstContacts.SelectedIndex].zipcodestring = "";

    firstname.Text = "Add a new Contact";
    lastname.Text = "";
    streetaddy.Text = "";
    city.Text = "";
    state.Text = "";
    zipcode.Text = "";

    int listselction = lstContacts.SelectedIndex;
    string removed = "Remove Contact";
    lstContacts.Items.Insert(listselction, removed);
    lstContacts.Items.RemoveAt(listselction + 1);
    lstContacts.ClearSelected();
    lstContacts.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: an index out of range error while deleting means the current item does not excist in the list. run this project while debugging and see what the item is you want to delete

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint at line

```
lstContacts.Items.RemoveAt(listselction + 1);
```

and look which value `listselction` has. Then check, if `.Items` contains so many items. Remember that the index starts at `0`. You are probably trying to delete with an index greater or equal then ´.Items.Count - 1`.

Comment: I did a breakpoint I got this output:

> Unit10_C.exe!Unit10_C.Unit10_C.deletebtn_Click(object sender = {Text = "&Delete"}, System.EventArgs e = {X = 30 Y = 16 Button = Left}) Line 98 C#

Comment: @allencoded: Please move the mouse of `listselction` and see which value it has.

Comment: move the mouse? not sure what you mean

Comment: I found the locals and seen listselction has the value of 0

Comment: @allencoded: Are you using VisualStudio? Which version? Have you ever debugged a program?

Comment: visual express edition 2008 its all they let us use in class. I have never debugged per say. In fact C# isn't really my forte.

Comment: If `.Items.Count` has a value of `1` at the breakpoint I mentioned above, then there will be an error, if you want to remove an item with an index of ´1´, because the highest index in this case is `0`!